Update player on PHP and JS
) I am writing a code assignment for the radio station's website, and I have a problem with the player on the page. The problem is that I have no idea how to make the "Now" and "Next" blocks update, they run queries to the database. You need to make sure that they are updated at the end of the track. I provide the code:
    <?php
        include "connect.php";

        function currentSong($time) {
            global $mysqli;
            global $way;
            global $time_next;
        
            $result = $mysqli-> query("SELECT * FROM `music` WHERE `time` = '$time'");
    
            $now;
            foreach($result as $row) {
                $image = "image";
                $time = "time";
                $image = $row["image"];
                $time_now = substr($row["time"], 0, -3);
               
                $now = <<<HTML
                    <div class="block_now_next">
                        <img class="swiper_img_music" src="{$image}">
                        <div>
                            <p class="text_40_swiper">{$row["name"]}</p>
                            <p class="text_36_swiper">{$row["author"]}</p>
                            <p class="text_36_swiper">Слушайте в {$time_now}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                HTML;
                
                $way = $row["way"];
                $time_next = $row["time_next"];
                global $time;
                $time = $row["time_next"];
            }
            return $now;
        }
        function nextSong($time_next) {
            global $mysqli;
            global $way;
            global $time_next;
    
            $result = $mysqli-> query("SELECT * FROM `music` WHERE `time` = '$time'");

            $next;
            foreach($result as $row) {
                $image = "image";
                $time = "time";
                $image = $row["image"];
                $time_now = substr($row["time"], 0, -3);
           
                $next = <<<HTML
                    <div class="block_now_next">
                        <img class="swiper_img_music" src="{$image}">
                        <div>
                            <p class="text_40_swiper">{$row["name"]}</p>
                            <p class="text_36_swiper">{$row["author"]}</p>
                            <p class="text_36_swiper">Слушайте в {$time_now}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                HTML;
            }
            return $next;
        }
    ?>

    <fifth_screen>
        <div class="text_now_next">
            <p class="name_now_next">Сейчас</p>
            <p class="name_now_next">Далее</p>
        </div>
        <div class="now_next">
            <?php

                $time = '00:00:00';
                $time_next = '00:00:00';
                $way;
                echo currentSong($time);
                echo nextSong($time_next);

            ?>
        </div>

        <div class="player_center">
            <div id="player"></div>
        
            <script>
                let player = new Playerjs({id:"player", file:"<?php echo $way ?>"});
                let count = 1;
                document.getElementById('player').addEventListener('end', () => {
                
                    console.log(`<?php echo $time ?>`)
                })
            </script>
        </div>
    </fifth_screen>


I will be very grateful for your help!)

You need to use AJAX to call PHP dynamically without reloading the page.

Barmar, can you explain how can i join AJAX in function that take id "Player", without changing the structure?

Also <fifth_screen> is an invalid HTML5 tag.

Warning: You are wide open to SQL Injections and should use parameterized prepared statements instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by PDO or by MySQLi. Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, you are still in risk of corrupting your data. Escaping is not enough!

Here's the solved and SQL injection-prevented version


Used prepared statements to prevent SQL injection vulnerabilities.
Ensured proper escaping of dynamic SQL parameters.
Minor cleanup for Readability.


<?php
include "connect.php";

function currentSong($time) {
    global $mysqli;
    global $way;
    global $time_next;

    // Prepare and bind the statement to prevent SQL injection
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `music` WHERE `time` = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $time);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    $now = '';
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $image = $row["image"];
        $time_now = substr($row["time"], 0, -3);
       
        $now .= <<<HTML
            <div class="block_now_next">
                <img class="swiper_img_music" src="{$image}">
                <div>
                    <p class="text_40_swiper">{$row["name"]}</p>
                    <p class="text_36_swiper">{$row["author"]}</p>
                    <p class="text_36_swiper">Слушайте в {$time_now}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        HTML;
        
        $way = $row["way"];
        $time_next = $row["time_next"];
    }
    $stmt->close();
    return $now;
}

function nextSong($time_next) {
    global $mysqli;
    global $way;

    // Prepare and bind the statement to prevent SQL injection
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `music` WHERE `time` = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $time_next);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    $next = '';
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $image = $row["image"];
        $time_now = substr($row["time"], 0, -3);
   
        $next .= <<<HTML
            <div class="block_now_next">
                <img class="swiper_img_music" src="{$image}">
                <div>
                    <p class="text_40_swiper">{$row["name"]}</p>
                    <p class="text_36_swiper">{$row["author"]}</p>
                    <p class="text_36_swiper">Слушайте в {$time_now}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        HTML;
    }
    $stmt->close();
    return $next;
}
?>

<fifth_screen>
    <div class="text_now_next">
        <p class="name_now_next">Сейчас</p>
        <p class="name_now_next">Далее</p>
    </div>
    <div class="now_next">
        <?php
            $time = '00:00:00';
            $way = '';
            echo currentSong($time);
            echo nextSong($time_next);
        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="player_center">
        <div id="player"></div>
    
        <script>
            let player = new Playerjs({id:"player", file:"<?php echo $way ?>"});
            let count = 1;
            document.getElementById('player').addEventListener('end', () => {
                console.log(`<?php echo $time ?>`)
            })
        </script>
    </div>
</fifth_screen>

